# How to train word2vec with your own vocab

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

I am getting error while training word2vec with my own vocabulary. I am also not getting why its happening.

Code:

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

sentences = word2vec.LineSentence('test_data')

model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=20)
model.build_vocab(sentences,update=True)
model.train(sentences)

print model.most_similar(['course'])
```

It throws an error

```
2017-08-27 16:50:04,590 : INFO : precomputing L2-norms of word weight vectors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tryword2vec.py", line 23, in <module>
    print model.most_similar(['course']) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1285, in most_similar
    return self.wv.most_similar(positive, negative, topn, restrict_vocab, indexer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 97, in most_similar
    raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
KeyError: "word 'course' not in vocabulary"
```

test_data contains:

> Bachelor of Engg is a course. M.Tech is a course. ME is a course.
>   B.Tech is a course. Bachelor of Arts is a course. Fashion Design is a
>   course. Multimedia is a course. Mechanical engg is a course. Computer
>   Science is a course. Electronics is a cource. Engineering is a course.
>   MBA is a course. BBA is a course.

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the error is because the word **course** is not in the vocabulary. Instead the word present is **course.**

There is a period **"."** at the end of course.

check your vocabulary 
`model.wv.vocab`

```
{u'a': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fe086c461d0>,
 u'course.': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fe0b4704f90>,
 u'is': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fe086ba0d10>}
```

And do hide your **api** keys.

Comment: Right. why only 'a','course','is' are  visible in vocab not Bachelor of Engg, B.Tech, ME etc. Is there any way to check about it.